# Why is my Python test case failing in this coding challenge?

Tags: python

Here is the problem:

> Given a string, return the count of the number of times that a
>   substring length 2 appears in the string and also as the last 2 chars
>   of the string, so "hixxxhi" yields 1 (we won't count the end
>   substring).
>
> last2('hixxhi') → 1 last2('xaxxaxaxx') → 1 last2('axxxaaxx') → 2

My Solution::

```
def last2(str):
  excl_last2 = str[:-2];
  list_excl_last2=[];

  for i in range(len(excl_last2)-1):
    list_excl_last2.append(excl_last2[i:i+2]);
  count = 0;
  for i in list_excl_last2:
    if str[-2:] == i:
      count = count + 1;
  return count;
```

It passes for all test cases except the one which is if str = 'xxxx'. My program returns 1. The expected output is 2. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're removing the last two characters from the string before you scan it for matches. So `excl_last2 = 'xx'` in that test case, and there's only one match there.

You should just remove the last character, not the last two characters.

BTW, you shouldn't use the names of standard functions as your variable names. `str` and `count` are standard built-in functions

You can do the counting in the first loop, rather than constructing a list of substrings.

```
def last2(string):
  excl_last1 = string[:-1];
  last2 = string[-2:]
  ct = 0
  for i in range(len(excl_last2)-1):
    if excl_last2[i:i+2] == last2:
      ct += 1
  return ct
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def last2(str):
  last2chars = str[len(str)-2:];
  count=0;
  for i in range(len(str)-2):
    if str[i:i+2]==last2chars:
      count = count + 1;  
  return count;
```

The above code passed all test cases. Thanks to Barmar for his logical
explanation for the failing test case; as per suggestion I modified it, now it seems to pass all test cases.